# Importing large amount of Products to Woocomerce via XML. What's the best method?

Tags: xml, woocommerce, wpallimport

I want to import in Woocommerce a large XML file with multiple images associated to it.

I have 3 choices:

1. Download it via WP all import plugin. I tried and it crashs and takes forever despite having a top server. I am not happy with this solution unless I find a way to insert the images in the product gallery via an attribute and link the image to a CDN. I can only imagine the maintenance to be a nightmare.
2. Use wp wc cli: via a ruby/python script that will call the XML and introduce all the corresponding values. Never tried it.
3. Direct Import to my database: I heard it was tricky with Woocommerce since lots of association.

   Anyone has a comment it would be welcome prior to embarking on this journey.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: I use MySQL. XML file with about 18000 products having about 20 elements each. Total is about 50G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, the easiest method for me was to use a command-line script to utilize the Woocommerce REST API to handle the creation of the products. For images, you'll need to use the standard Wordpress REST API, which isn't the best documented.

Using this route, you'll need to definitely write a script to parse your XML and then hand the data off to the REST API to perform the creation of the products in the store.

I'd recommend the following method of creating your products:

1. Do an initial first pass of your data to create your global attributes, taxonomies, categories, etc. You'll want to do this first, as a lot of the product data you'll need to send in your CRUD calls uses the ID of the post,taxonomy, etc.
2. Create your products. You'll use the data set up in step 1 to do the assignment of your variations and categories. If you're dealing with variable products and product variations, make sure to create the parent first and assign the variation meta data.
3. Perform the image upload portion. You'll be able to create the media library entries with the WP REST API and then update the product posts with the WC REST API.

Depending on how many products you have, you may want to look at adding in some functionality in the import script to set a start, stop, and offset point. For example, only run 200 product nodes starting with the 101st product node. This works nicely as you can then open up multiple prompts to do some poor-man's multi-threading.

Some things to look out for:

- Your script may time out to the server, especially if the computer goes to sleep. This is where having a starting point in your script is nice, in case you need to restart at a certain point.
- The process can be a bit slow. There's plenty of bottlenecks you can run into (HTTP call overhead, slow connection, etc).
- The Wordpress REST API is poorly documented. For uploading images, you'll just need to do a similar call.  :

```
// PHP - Use Wordpress REST API Library to upload an image.
$imagedata     = file_get_contents("myimagefile.jpg");
$upload_result = $wordpress->post('media', [
    'body'    => $imagedata,
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type'        => 'image/jpg',
        'content-disposition' => 'attachment; filename=myimagefile.jpg'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: That's precious information. I will probably follow your advice! :) Many thanks.